# is it possible to delete an email from outlook or outlookexpress programatically?

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2007-addin

I want to know if it is possibel to create a COM component to monitor emails commin into Outlook 2007? 
I mean I just want to develop an addin kind of component which when loaded to Outlook should monitor the emails. Monitoring emails in the sense, is it possible to note the from email? and perfom some action such as delete that email?

Can anyone plese let me know the interfaces that I need to use? cosidering anything like c#,vc++ anything at all, where we can develop a COM component

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do it programmatically but it's easier to create a rule in Outlook that does what you want.

Comment: I am interested in controlling thru addin