# Is there a way to permanently delete (shift+del equiv) emails from Outlook using PowerShell?

Tags: email, powershell, outlook

I have written a PowerShell script to delete all emails and inbox subfolders of a secondary mailbox open in my Outlook profile but to leave the rest of a users' mailbox intact. I want to know if there's a way of doing it without sending everything to the Deleted Items folder first.

I am working remotely over a VPN and this unnecessary step of moving files into my Delete Items is both slow and an annoying inconvenience. Is there any script equivalent to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>?

Get-Member returns the following list of methods for the mail item object type. I've been using the Delete method but I can't find the object type reference on MSDN to have a closer look at its methods to see if Delete will take a parameter to permanently delete for example.

```
   TypeName: System.__ComObject#{00063034-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}

Name                              MemberType Definition                                            
----                              ---------- ----------                                            
AddBusinessCard                   Method     void AddBusinessCard (ContactItem)                    
ClearConversationIndex            Method     void ClearConversationIndex ()                        
ClearTaskFlag                     Method     void ClearTaskFlag ()                                 
Close                             Method     void Close (OlInspectorClose)                         
Copy                              Method     IDispatch Copy ()                                     
Delete                            Method     void Delete ()                                        
Display                           Method     void Display (Variant)                                
Forward                           Method     MailItem Forward ()                                   
MarkAsTask                        Method     void MarkAsTask (OlMarkInterval)                      
Move                              Method     IDispatch Move (MAPIFolder)                           
PrintOut                          Method     void PrintOut ()                                      
Reply                             Method     MailItem Reply ()                                     
ReplyAll                          Method     MailItem ReplyAll ()                                  
Save                              Method     void Save ()                                          
SaveAs                            Method     void SaveAs (string, Variant)                         
Send                              Method     void Send ()                                          
ShowCategoriesDialog              Method     void ShowCategoriesDialog ()
```

My script looks like this at the moment:

```
# Initialise variables
$TargetMailbox = "Mailbox - User"

# SCRIPT BODY
# ===========

# Connect to Outlook
$Outlook = New-Object -comobject Outlook.Application

# Select the mailbox by name
$Mailbox = $Outlook.Session.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $TargetMailbox}

# Select Inbox by name
$Inbox = $Mailbox.Folders | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "Inbox" }

# Delete subfolders
$Inbox.Folders | foreach {
    write-host "Deleting Inbox\$($_.Name) (Folder)"
    $_.Delete()
}

# Delete items
$Inbox.Items | foreach {
    write-host "Deleting Inbox\$($_.subject) (Item)"
    $_.Delete()
}
```

Comment: Reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974472/is-it-possible-to-delete-an-email-from-outlook-or-outlookexpress-programatically?rq=1, I won't post as duplicate since the other question doesn't have an implementation.

Comment: Well here is the MSDN object reference for the MailItem object (Outlook 2010) -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861252(v=office.14).aspx.  Not much help there, though.  My limited googlin' doesn't reveal any answers.  You wouldn't happen to have access to the EMS on the Exchange Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to Exchange using the EWS libraries, the model to talk to your own mailbox is very straightforward. On the Delete method there's a hard Delete, Soft Delete and Mode to trash option. Since it by-passes the local Outlook profile altogether it would use the standard Server Sync to get that back in sync, which is the fastest way I know of.

This sample clears up a calendar, but the trick would be very similar for other folders.

```
_service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
//Connect directly to the EWS uri, or use AutoDiscover
_service.Url = new Uri(ExchangeServerUri);
_service.Credentials = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

ItemView view = new ItemView(100, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning);
view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(PropertySet.IdOnly);
view.PropertySet.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);
view.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.Start);
view.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.End);
view.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType);
view.PropertySet.Add(AppointmentSchema.TimeZone);
view.Traversal = ItemTraversal.Shallow;

Console.WriteLine("Fetching appointments for {0}", Mailbox);

FolderId folder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(Mailbox));

foreach (var item in folder.Items)
     _service.DeleteItems(new[] { item.Id }, DeleteMode.HardDelete, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone, AffectedTaskOccurrence.AllOccurrences);
```

Other advantage is that it doesn't require outlook to be installed, no security issues around COM automation objects etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can either call `MailItem.Delete`, then find that deleted item in the Deleted Items folder (e.g. using some custom property) and delete it again (this time permanently) by calling `MailItem.Delete`.

You can also use Redemption (I am its author), which can be used alongside the Outlook Object Model  and its [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`Delete` method - it takes an optional `DeleteFlags` parameter (`dfSoftDelete`, `dfMoveToDeletedItems`, `dfHardDelete`).